# SparkSession Application Source Code Config Properties not Overriding JupyterHub & Zeppelin on AWS EMR defaults

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I have Spark Driver setup to use `Zeppelin` and or `JupyterHub` as client for interactive Spark Programming on `AWS EMR`.  However, when I create the `SparkSession` with custom config properties *(application name, # of cores, executor ram, # of executors, serializer, etc)* it is not overriding the default values for those configs (confirmed under Environment tab in `Spark UI` and `spark.conf.get(...)`).

Like any Spark App these clients on `EMR` should be using my custom config properties because `SparkSession` code is the 1st highest override before spark-submit, spark config file, and then spark-defaults.  `JupyterHub` also immediately launches a Spark Application w/o coding one or when just running an empty cell.

*Is there a setting specific to `Zeppelin`, `JupyterHub`, or a separate xml conf that needs adjusted to get custom configs recognized and working?*  Any help is much appreciated.

Example of creating a basic application where these cluster resource configs should be implemented instead of the standard default configs which is what is happening with `Zeppelin/JupyterHub` on `EMR`.

```py
# via zep or jup [configs NOT being recognized]
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName("app_name")\
.master("yarn")\
.config("spark.submit.deployMode","client")\
.config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")\
.config("spark.executor.instances", 11)\
.config("spark.executor.cores", 5)\
.config("spark.executor.memory", "19g")\
.getOrCreate()

# via ssh terminal [configs ARE recognized at run-time]
pyspark \
--name "app_name" \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 11 \
--executor-cores 5 \
--executor-memory 19 \
--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
```

Comment: Are all set configuration ignored or just some of them? Some properties have to be set when invoking the 'spark-submit' command, YARN ignores them once the resources are allocated.

Comment: all of them are being ignored ... never have experienced this odd behavior on cloudera or databricks via their notebook clients

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  The `config.json` file under `/etc/jupyter/conf` had some default spark config values hence I removed them to display an empty json key/value like => `_configs":{}`.  Creating a custom `SparkSession` via `JupyterHub` now understands the specified cluster configs.

These magic commands are always working `%%configure`

https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic